# Incompatible Types Error When Converting/Transferring ArrayList<String> data to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, compiler-errors

I'm trying to take the values I have gathered into an ArrayList of Strings and transfer them over into an array of Strings so that I can run the data through an algorithm that accepts arrays. I am able to do this in the main method, though this is not effective because the data must be run through multiple sorting algorithms and so I need to create the array again each time I call the algorithm. I decided to write it into it's own method for efficiency. However, the same exact code throws an error if I place it in a separate method.

Here is the culprit:

```
public static String[] transferDefs(ArrayList defs){
//Copy ArrayList values into String[] for sorting
String[] a = new String[defs.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < defs.size(); i++){
  a[i] = defs.get(i); //THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
}
return a;
```

}

I have also tried using the ArrayList.toArray() method rather than a `for` loop. The same problem occurs.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just write `ArrayList<String> defs` instead.

Comment: You're using raw types for ```ArrayList defs```, so it's having a type mismatch. You need to use ```ArrayList<String>```

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Just write `List<String>` defs instead ([here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
public static String[] transferDefs(ArrayList<String> defs) {
    // Copy ArrayList values into String[] for sorting
    String[] a = new String[defs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < defs.size(); i++) {
        a[i] = defs.get(i); // THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
    }
    return a;
}
```